# Concatenating list from a function to another recursive function in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

So I am trying to code a relatively simple function in OCaml which takes an integer n and a list of integers up to 5 and then repeats all integers above 1 in said list n times.

I already have an existing function repeat which repeats whatever I feed it n times

```
let rec repeat : int -> 'a -> 'a list =
 fun n a ->  
  match n with  
  | 0 -> []  
  | h -> a :: repeat (h-1) a ;;
```

Now here is the code for the function called Pentograph

```
let pentograph : int -> int list-> int list =
  fun n letter ->
    match letter with 
    |[] -> []
    |h::t -> if h>1 then List.concat[(repeat n h);pentograph n t] else List.conca[h;pentograph n t];;
```

I get the following error:

> Error: Unbound value pentograph

On trying to use the :: operator I get an error too as I can not use it to concat 2 lists.

Please help me figure out a solution to this problem!

EDIT: If the correct answer or more optimal answer uses map then please answer with that instead of trying to fix my code.

Comment: Recursive functions need to include the `rec` keyword. `let rec pentograph = ... `

Comment: `::` does not concatenate two lists. Rather it attaches a value to the front of a list. For concatenation, use `@`: `list1 @ list2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists in Ocaml are a variant type with some syntactic sugar vs. your typical user-defined variant type. A list is either an empty list (`[]`) or some element of type `'a` tacked onto a list with the `::` operator. As this is a recursive type, it's unsurprising that we use recursion to work on them.

Lists can also be concatenated with the `@` operator.

Your `repeat` function is good. I'm going to leave out the explicit types and reformat it a bit:

```ml
let rec repeat n a =
  match n with
  | 0 -> []
  | _ -> a :: repeat (n - 1) a
```

You've defined an exit condition. If we ask the function to repeat something `0` times, we get an empty list. Otherwise we tack `a` onto the front of the result of repeating the function with one less repetition. This second stage sets up an update to the state which moves it closer to the exit condition.

```
repeat 4 6
6 :: repeat 3 6
6 :: 6 :: repeat 2 6
6 :: 6 :: 6 :: repeat 1 6
6 :: 6 :: 6 :: 6 :: repeat 0 6
[6; 6; 6; 6]
```

So, do the same thing with your `pentograph` function. It takes a number of time to repeat, and a list. We can recursively iterate through the list, so the natural exit condition is an empty list. If the list is empty, the result should be an empty list.

```ml
let rec pentograph n lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
```

Otherwise the list will be some value and a remainder of the list.

```ml
let rec pentograph n lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | x::xs -> ...
```

Now we know that `x` is the first element of the list, so we can check if it is greater than 1.

```ml
let rec pentograph n lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | x::xs -> 
      if x > 1 then ...
      else ...
```

If it's greater than 1, we'll farm out the repetition work to `repeat` and tack that onto the front of running `pentograph` on the rest of the list. If it's not, we'll just run the `pentograph` function on the rest of the list, ignoring `x` in our result.

```ml
let rec pentograph n lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | x::xs -> 
      if x > 1 then 
        repeat n x :: pentograph n xs
      else 
        pentograph n xs
```

Now, let's try evaluating this for `pentograph 2 [1; 2; 3]`.

```
pentograph 2 [1; 2; 3]
pentograph 2 [2; 3]
repeat 2 2 :: pentograph 2 [3]
repeat 2 2 :: repeat 2 3 :: pentograph 2 []
repeat 2 2 :: repeat 2 3 :: []
[2; 2] :: [3; 3] :: []
[[2; 2]; [3; 3]]
```

Now, the result you're probably looking for is `[2; 2; 3; 3]`, so we can replaced list construction with list *concatenation*.

```ml
let rec pentograph n lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | x::xs -> 
      if x > 1 then 
        repeat n x @ pentograph n xs
      else 
        pentograph n xs
```

And now:

```
pentograph 2 [1; 2; 3]
pentograph 2 [2; 3]
repeat 2 2 @ pentograph 2 [3]
repeat 2 2 @ repeat 2 3 @ pentograph 2 []
repeat 2 2 @ repeat 2 3 @ []
[2; 2] @ [3; 3] @ []
[2; 2; 3, 3]
```

Finally, as a stylistic preference, we can use guards on the pattern matching, rather than if/else to clean it up a bit.

```ml
let rec pentograph n lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | x::xs when x > 1 -> repeat n x @ pentograph n xs
  | _::xs -> pentograph n xs
```